# How to override and call super for response_change or response_add in django admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, nonetype

I would like to override `response_change` in a ModelAdmin in order to update a field in the parent window. After doing the update, I'd like to give control back to the overriden `response_change`.

A simplified version of what I have tried is:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        // perfom my actions
        super(MyModelAdmin, self).response_change(request, obj)
```

But I get an AttributeError - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'has_header'. Maybe, I'm not using super properly...?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to actually return the result of the call to super().

```
return super(MyModelAdmin, self).response_change(request, obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add a more detailed stacktrace?

Where does the Error occur? Do you create a response? Otherwise `get_response` might implicitly return `None` therefor the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return **"super().response_change(request, obj)"** as shown below:

```py
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        // perfom my actions
        return super().response_change(request, obj) # Here
```